# Did you see Luke and Biggs on Tatooine at one of the 1977 screenings of Star Wars ("A New Hope")? If so, can you please provide corroboration?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, tatooine

I saw *Star Wars* in the theater seven times during 1977 and know for a fact that I saw the scene of Luke and Biggs on Tatooine on the big screen during the first showing that I ever saw.  I also clearly remember noting that the scene was not in any subsequent screenings that I saw that year.

Folks online have noted that there must have been a cut of the film showing Luke and Biggs on Tatooine because the scene is referenced in the Marvel comic book and *The Star Wars Storybook*, merchandising items that would have been produced prior to the film's release.  The people who produced those items must have been working with, or referencing, that particular cut.  (Others, however, have suggested that one's "memory" of the scene on film is simply a product of reading the Marvel comic book or *The Star Wars Storybook*.  That may sound plausible, but it's not in my case.)

When I first saw the movie, my parents and I were among the last people to get into the theater.  As such, we ended up sitting in the first or second row.  My memory of seeing Luke and Biggs on opposite sides of that giant screen is thus *very* distinct, and *very*, *very* different from seeing that scene in the Marvel comic book or the *Storybook*.

So: we can conclude that, given the scene's presence in the comic book and the *Storybook*, there was almost certainly a cut that the producers of those books were working to that included the Tatooine scene (and, of course, the *Storybook* actually includes images from the scene, which strongly implies that there was at some point an intent to release the film with the scene included).  If the cut exists (or existed), it's possible that it made its way into some theaters along with the "original" cut.  (Stuff happens.)

Anyway, I wouldn't just say "it's possible".  I'd say that that's exactly what happened -- because I saw the scene myself.

Thus my question: Were you one of the people who also saw the scene in the theater in 1977?  If so, please provide details about your experience.

Comment: Yes and no.  My question pertains, not to speculation about the scene, but to those who actually claim to have seen it in 1977.  I'm asking them to provide corroborating details, etc.  There is indeed someone on that thread who claims to have a memory of that scene without having seen the Marvel comic, the Storybook, or any of the outtakes/deleted scenes on YouTube, etc.  I'm asking for more such data.

Comment: I would assume that your answer to the first part of my question is "no".  Which is fine.  That lets folks know that there probably won't be any relevant data coming from you.  But if you do have some, I'd love to hear it.  Best,

Comment: It's a deleted scene. It may have been shown at a test screening, but I've never seen any evidence that it went out to general release, even by accident. It seems more likely that people are misremembering it being in the film because of the comic and novelisation containing the scene.

Comment: You should say the name of your theater.  Sorry but this will likely be closed.  Trying to do a survey when your own example has very little data has obvious problems if you are trying to establish an anomalous film print existing.  I'm sure a Biggs Google search will turn up a message board better suited to your goals.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of the fact that the scene was deleted from the "official" release.  That doesn't clarify anything here or constitute any sort of refutation.  (And, of course, remember that Lucas released an updated version in 1978.  He and others involved in the film were tinkering with it while it was in theaters.)  The question here pertains to an earlier cut (and there is clear evidence that such a cut existed, thanks to the Marvel comic and the Star Was Storybook) and whether or not (or to what extent) prints of that cut trickled into release.

Comment: The theater where I first saw it was in Rochester, Michigan.  It's been closed for probably 20 years.  I think it's a Rite Aid these days.  My memory of the scene (and its visual dynamics) could not be derived from the Marvel comic or the Storybook.  The way that Luke and Biggs were mostly shot on opposite halves of the screen is not captured or conveyed in those static images.  And, like I said, I watched that scene from the first or second row.  Seeing Luke and Biggs on opposite halves of that giant screen is a very distinct (not a fuzzy) memory.  It corresponds perfectly to the outtakes.

Comment: I would add the following: 1) It's possible that test screening cuts with the Tatooine scene accidentally made their way into some theaters.  That's not at all far-fetched.  But I would also add that, 2) given the huge demand for the film, prints of this earlier (and ultimately "rejected") cut may have later been released in order to meet demand.